# Show modal after download for multiple download links

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap

i have many download links. i want to open the same modal after clicking each download link. I achieved this for a single download by creating two links, one for the modal and one for the download, hiding the download link and then triggerring the click event on it when the modal link is clicked. the only problem is that it isnt working for multiple download links. I tried using different ids on the links for each file and triggering each dwnload from a seperate modal link but it isnt working.

```
<ul class="list-group">
   <li class="list-group-item">2016
     <a class="pull-right" href="#" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal" rel="nofollow" download id="modal1"><i class='fa fa-download'>Download</i></a>
     <a href="https://drive.google.com/uc?export=download&id=0Bw41ZfJHqw5IU01JQ0haanBfOFE" id="download1" class="hidden">aa</a></li>
   <li class="list-group-item">2015
     <a class="pull-right" href="#" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal" rel="nofollow" download id="modal2"><i class='fa fa-download'>Download</i></a>
     <a href="https://drive.google.com/uc?export=download&id=0Bw41ZfJHqw5IWjZiM0ozNEVNZFU" id="download2" class="hidden">aa</a></li>
  </ul>
```

those are the links. this is the modal;

```
div class="modal fade" id="myModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
  <div class="modal-dialog">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">&times;</button>
        <h4 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel">Your download will begin shortly...</h4>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
        this is the modal body
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

this is the javascript

```
$('[data-toggle=modal]').on('click', function(e) {
  var $target = $($(this).data('target'));
  $target.data('triggered', true);
  setTimeout(function() {
    if ($target.data('triggered')) {
      $target.modal('show').data('triggered', false);
    };
  }, 1000); // milliseconds
  return false;
});

$('#modal1').click(function(){
  $('#download1').trigger('click');
});
$('#modal2').click(function(){
  $('#download2').trigger('click');
});
```

please what is wrong?

Comment: duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/a/29226666/3774282

Comment: Its not really the same.  The modal is opening but the download links are not working